# How do you indentify which functions are Zend functions as opposed to made ones?

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to Zend and very keen to learn. Quick question.

I am going through the script of a social forums site that was build using Zend framework 1.12. I noticed however, that the designer built the site using a lot of native Zend functions. i.e helper functions like _getFormData.

I was wondering therefore, is there a way for me, when reading a script, to be able to tell which are native Zend functions and which were designed by the previous designer.

I am using net bean (for example, in procedural PHP native PHP functions like `count()`, `date()` etc. are always rendered in a different color than self made functions)

Also, is the a list of all the different Zend functions: I mean, apart from going to each class and studying all the methods within that class. Is there somewhere that I can go to get a full list of all the different methods within classes.?

Comment: You should use Zend Framework 2

Comment: If you use an IDE like PHP Storm, then it will auto complete for you with docblocs.